# Unity взбирание на возвышенность

Tags: unity3d

На игроке установлен rigidbody. При подъеме на крутой склон все работает как надо: игрок не может подниматься при определенном угле склона. Но, если во время подъема еще и прыгать (прыгает с помощью addforce), то без труда можно подняться на крутую возвышенность. Как такое можно исправить?

```
public float jumpForce;  
Rigidbody rb; 
void Start(){
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}
void Update() { 
    Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position + transform.up, -transform.up);
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, 1.1f)) {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Приведи полный код прыжка, addforce можно применять очень по-разному.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker public float jumpForce;
    RaycastHit info;
    Rigidbody rb;
    void Update()
    {
        Ray ray = new Ray(transform.position + transform.up, -transform.up);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, 1.1f))
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                    rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpForce);
            }
            
        }
    }

Comment: @RiotBr3aker извини, что все в одну строчку. Я пока только начинаю пользоваться сайтом и еще не знаю как здесь код публиковать

Comment: Лучше добавлять эту информацию в сам вопрос, а не писать в комментариях :)

Comment: А у тебя есть проверка, находится ли персонаж на земле или нет?

Comment: Да, есть. Проверка рейкастом

Comment: @RiotBr3aker я думаю, может как-то проверять угол наклонности поверхности, на которой стоит персонаж и если угол достаточно большой, то запрещать прыгать? Ну это просто мои соображения

Comment: Нужно сильно ослабить воздействие игрока во время прыжка, чтобы движение влево и вправо не так сильно влияло. Я в данный момент не у пк, так что смогу адекватно расписать только завтра.

Comment: Понял тебя. Спасибо, сейчас подумаю над этим